# C言語のソース?にバイナリを埋め込む方法

Tags: c

C言語で書いているプログラムで固定の画像を使いたいのですが、マルチプラットフォームなのでプログラムのバイナリに埋め込んでしまうのが一番手っ取り早いと思います。
ソースに入れる必要はありませんが、環境ごとに違う「リソース」の様なものは避けたいです。何か良い方法はあるでしょうか。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

補足。Linuxではxxdコマンドに-iオプションを指定するとバイナリデータをC言語形式に変換できます。

```
$ xxd -i 1x1.png
unsigned char __1x1_png[] = {
  0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d,
  0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0x15, 0xc4, 0x89, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x06, 0x62, 0x4b, 0x47, 0x44, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xa0,
  0xbd, 0xa7, 0x93, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x70, 0x48, 0x59, 0x73, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x0b, 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0b, 0x13, 0x01, 0x00, 0x9a, 0x9c, 0x18,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x49, 0x44, 0x41, 0x54, 0x08, 0xd7, 0x63, 0xf8,
  0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x09, 0xfb, 0x03, 0xfd, 0xd1, 0x83, 0x8c,
  0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x44, 0xae, 0x42, 0x60,
  0x82
};
unsigned int __1x1_png_len = 109;
```

Answer (score 4):

`unsigned char`の配列として持つことになると思います。

例えば、

```
int main(void){
    extern unsigned char bindata[];
    //bindata を用いた処理
}
```

のようにして
`addBin program.c data.bin`
のようなプログラムで、プログラムの末尾に書き込みます。
すると、次のような形で埋め込まれる。

```
int main(void){
    extern unsigned char bindata[];//これはヘッダファイルにする方がいいかも
    //bindata を用いた処理
}
unsigned char bindata[] = {
24,45,68,84,251,33,9,64,};
```

あるいは末尾ではなく別のファイルに書き出して、コンパイルしておいて、リンクする。
`addBin databin.c data.bin` //databin.cは空または存在しないファイル

`gcc -c databin.c`
`gcc main.c databin.o`

addBin.c のサンプル

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s program_source data_file\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    FILE *fpw = fopen(argv[1], "a");
    FILE *fpr = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
    //fpw and fpr null check
    fprintf(fpw, "\nunsigned char bindata[] = {\n");
    int ch;
    while((ch = getc(fpr)) != EOF){
        fprintf(fpw, "%u,", ch);//適宜改行を入れる？
    }
    fprintf(fpw, "};\n");
    fprintf(fpw, "#include <stddef.h>\n");
    fprintf(fpw, "size_t bindata_size = sizeof bindata;\n");

    fclose(fpw);fclose(fpr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 他の方の回答を見て気が付いたんですが、配列のサイズが必要ですね。

Comment: 配列のサイズも書き出すように追加しました。